# Docker nginx proxy cannot access dhprams

Tags: docker, nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot, proxy-server

I generated ssl certificate using letsencrypte but when I ran my docker container this error came

```
proxy_1    | Checking for dhparams.pem
proxy_1    | Checking for fullchain.pem
proxy_1    | SSL cert exists, enabling HTTPS...
proxy_1    | 2022/12/01 22:31:45 [emerg] 8#8: PEM_read_bio_DHparams("/vol/proxy/ssl-dhparams.pem") failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: DH PARAMETERS)
proxy_1    | nginx: [emerg] PEM_read_bio_DHparams("/vol/proxy/ssl-dhparams.pem") failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: DH PARAMETERS)
```

It should start proxy server with ssl
I am following this guide and I don not know how to fix this
https://londonappdeveloper.com/django-docker-deployment-with-https-using-letsencrypt/

Comment: Looks like that file is supposed to be created by a script called `run.sh`. Does that script run? Does it have errors?

Comment: The message means that, when opening the `dhparams.pem`, nginx is expecting to find a `-----BEGIN DH PARAMETERS-----` line (as well as a `-----END DH PARAMETERS-----` line at the end, see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94390/whats-the-purpose-of-dh-parameters) for an example file). So there's something wrong with the script creating it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on the same tuto, for some reason the dhparams.pem seemed corrupted or empty. I just removed the files by deleting the volumes

```
docker-compose down -v
```

then obtaining the certificate

```
docker-compose run --rm certbot /opt/certify-init.sh
```

and finally re-up the docker-compose (no re-build)

```
docker-compose up -d
```

For me that worked, I hope it can help someone.